# Linux kernel upgraded to version 6 for some reason

Tags: compute-module-4

Recently I did a sudo apt update/upgrade on my raspberry pi.  It is running 64 bit raspberry pi os (I think).  When I do `cat /etc/os-release` it shows that it is running debian 11 and the pretty name is debian GNU/Linux.  I noticed that after running the sudo update my cm4io-fan dkms module didn't work so I tried to reinstall it but it complained about missing linux headers.  I checked uname -r and it said I was running 5.15.something kernel.  When I tried to manually install header using `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` but it errored saying it couldn't find those moudles.  I double checked and apt said I was up to date.  So, I tried to just reboot the pi, but now I notice that when I run `uname -r` it shows linux kernel is 6.1.19.  This is strange.  I check apt to see which linux-image packages I have installed and it only shows 5.10 images.  dpkg shows no linux-image packages.  I am quite confused on what may be happening.  Most programs seem to work fine, but I cannot install my cm4io-fan module since it is hard coded to only install if I am running linux kernel version 5.  Also, it seems that the latest raspberry pi os should be using 5.15 linux kernel so I want to now what is going wrong with my linux install?

Comment: correct, raspberry pi current kernel is 6.1.19 - at least, in 64bit bullseye

Comment: as for lack of `"linux-image"` - it's called `raspberrypi-kernel` in pi land :p

Comment: and lastly, the cm4io-fan part of your question ... does [this](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2021/controlling-pwm-fans-raspberry-pi-cm4-io-boards-emc2301) help? I believe control is possible through the i2c-fan module for quite some time now

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!  I think this is everything I needed!!